# Sharepoint: Custom view permissions

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

I created a custom list to be used as a form on our Sharepoint 2007 Standard Server. When I click on “New Item” I can fill out the form but it goes back to the list with all the entered forms. I notice that there is NO permissions on the VIEW, but how can limit so that the user views only his created forms?

Comment: Why do you want to hide fields from the user? If the user has Contribute access, why shouldn't he be able to look at the list?

Comment: The majority of the users can view thier own created records (forms) but only a very few slected users can view all records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the "Only their own" option for item level permissions.

Start here:  http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=58

Comment: You could something like skyflyer suggested, but I would caution that it doesn't protect the data outside of the product.  That level of protection is only afforded by SharePoint permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The view can use a filter where Created By = [Me].